# How to prevent Android keyboard "OK" button from accepting my QDialog

Tags: android, qt

Running an app on Android, I have a `QDialog` with a few edit fields (`QLineEdit`) and a `QDialogButtonBox`. When user enters text in one of my `QLineEdit`, then press "OK" button from Android virtual keyboard, it accepts the dialog (as if I clicked "OK" on the `QDialogButtonBox`), while user expects to commit the text to the currently selected edit field so that he can move to the next one...

Sample program:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    MyDialog()
    {
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget( new QLineEdit( this ) );
        layout->addWidget( new QLineEdit( this ) );

        QDialogButtonBox* box = new QDialogButtonBox( QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel, Qt::Horizontal, this );
        connect( box, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()) );
        connect( box, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()) );
        layout->addWidget( box );
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyDialog dlg;
    dlg.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried to change Ok button default behaviour using:

```
box->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setAutoDefault( false );
box->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setDefault( false );
```

but it does not solve the problem. I'm really stuck with this, which is most likely a Qt bug ([reported it](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61652)).

Any idea how I could workaround that?

Considering that I have the issue in many dialogs, I'd like a generic solution (like a helper class I could attach to the `QDialog` or the `QDialogButtonBox`...), replacing the `QDialogButtonBox` by some standard buttons will hardly be an acceptable solution...

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice way to fix that for all input controls (`QLineEdit`but also `QSpinBox`) of every dialog by specializing `QApplication`:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;

    bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)
    {
        if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
        {
            QKeyEvent* ev = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>( event );
            if ( ev->key() == Qt::Key_Return )
            {
                if ( inputMethod() && inputMethod()->isVisible() )
                {
                    qDebug() << "fixing https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61652";

                    // "OK" was pressed on virtual keyboard
                    // let's close virtual keyboard
                    inputMethod()->hide();
                    // and also let's not propagate this event that would end up closing the QDialog:
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return QApplication::notify( receiver, event );
    }
};
```